# Azure lighthouse - cross tenant automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I am preparing automated solution in my Azure environment. I have to provide automation that will be able to manage resources in multiple Azure subscriptions spread across different Azure tenants. I am currently testing Azure Lighthouse, and its very useful service in case of backup and Update Management service management (multiple subscription, many tenants). In MS documentation - [Azure Lighthouse - cross-tenant-management-experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/concepts/cross-tenant-management-experience) there is a section `Azure Automation` and short description `Use Automation accounts to access and work with delegated resources`. Question is how does it work? I didn't find method how to run a runbook from one central subscription and manage resources (list VMs, Storage Account) in remote/customers subscription. Is there any way to use Azure Lighthouse for running Automation runbooks from one central point and manage resources in customer's account. I know that we can use Azure Monitor and create alerts and using them run runbooks to manage resources in customers accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not related to Azure Light house, but you can have an Automation Runbook to access multiple subscriptions by providing necessary permissions.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$Subs = Get-AzSubscription # filter by name
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Subs.Name
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $RunAsConnection.SubscriptionId

# Rest of your script goes here
```

Comment: ok, but what about multiple tenant environment? Does this solution work for multiple tenant envs?

Comment: Yes, Azure Light House offers multiple tenants handled by a service provider. Microsoft has also given ARM templates for adding new customers for management. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/lighthouse/how-to/onboard-customer.md

Comment: yes, yes, I know, Az Lighthouse allows us to cross tenant management, but how can we use that service in case of Azure Automation/running runbooks from one accounts to provide automation on many az accounts?

Comment: Once you delegate a service principal or a group across other tenant, you will be given access to the client tenant and their subscriptions. Just try a simple script like querying other tenant subscription rg's. To get the partner name or tenant id Get-AzManagementPartner

PartnerId   : 4977985
PartnerName : Test_Test_DPORTest
TenantId    : 1b1121dd-6900-412a-af73-e8d44f81e1c1
ObjectId    : aa67f786-0552-423e-8849-244ed12bf581
State       : Active